# How Can I implement monthly attendence chart (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, charts, asp.net-webpages

I have a aspx webpage in which I want to display employee's monthly attendance in a chart.
So suggest me which chart can I use to do this task and also how to implement it.

And chart must me able to show day,time,workinghours,daytype.

I already have a sql table for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various chart libraries for it. But I would suggest [CanvasJs](https://canvasjs.com/) or [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

These are super flexible and customizable. You can do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes I know that but how can I implement my requirments ?

Comment: To make some suggestions, need details of your requirements including the table structure.